# Как реализовать программу через python? Егэ информатика

Tags: python

Как реализовать программу на Python. Задание 12 Егэ.
(ответ:28)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

```py
def rep(x):
    while '222' in x or '888' in x:
        if '888' in x:
            x = x.replace('888', '2')

        else:
            x = x.replace('222', '8')
    return x
print(rep('8'*68))
```

Comment: Эмм... А задача то какая?

Comment: `print(28)` . .

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске. Опишите задание и вашу попытку решения

Comment: Ну как-же, сподвигнулся самостоятельно целый вопрос на форуме написать. Чем не попытка? :-)

Comment: @passant, без явного приведения кода или хотя бы наброска алгоритма своими словами, этот вопрос кандидат на биржу фрилансов, да и есть же правила: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic которым можно следовать и закрывать учебные вопросы, если в них нет попыток решения автором

Comment: @gil9red -  да я вообще за то, что-бы за такие вопросы банить без права восстановления. Мне тут за такую жесткость даже "на вид" ставили :-) Ну а тут - вообще апофеоз -  даже саму  формулировку задач ТС сподобился привести -  причем даже не переписать, а просто отсканировать -   через 2 часа после закрытия вопроса. А мы не оценили его усилия.

Answer (score 1):

```
res1 = print("Задание ЕГЭ №12")
res2 = input("Введите данные:")
print("Ответ", len(str(res1)) * (2 + len(str(res2 == res1))))
```

Comment: и где в моем коде ошибка, что кто-то минусит?

Comment: надо было как я сделать «общим»